# transforming data for multiple regression with level-level and log-level variables

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation

I have two independent variables $A$ and $B$ which I would like to incorporate into a multiple regression for dependent variable $Y$. So far...

$Y = \alpha A$

and

$log(Y) = \beta + \alpha B$

...give good results i.e. strong positive linear association. But how should I transform $A$ or $B$ to incorporate into a multiple regression?

For those interested, the data I am working with can be downloaded from [here](http://www2.geog.ucl.ac.uk/~ucfaptv/regression_so.csv).

Comment: One option is: Y = b + a1 * A + a2 * exp(B)

Comment: Should it matter that $Y = \alpha e^B$ gives me a poorer result than $log(Y) = \alpha B$? Or is this unavoidable?

Comment: It is not expected I would say. Is it still true if you keep the intercept term?

Comment: **library(data.table); dat <- data.table(y = rnorm(100, 10, 1)); dat[, x1 := log(y) + rnorm(100, 0, 0.01)]; summary(lm(log(y) ~ x1, data = dat)); summary(lm(y ~ exp(x1), data = dat))** I don't post it as the ansewer, since I don't know why exactly estimates differ, but what I observe on my dummy data is that estimates are pretty close.